# How to set button's text invisible?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have some buttons and I have some text set ot them and I need that text to be visible when activity starts. After that I set some text to all my buttons from sqlite database, but I don't want that text to be visible until user clicks of a button.

The simplest solution would be to use button.setText(c.getString(int)); and set that text from db when a button is clicked, but my c cursor is not in activity scope so I can't use it in my onClick method of my buttons. I tried to place everything inside of my nextQuestion() method in activity scope, but that gives me errors.

So I was thinking I should hide all text set from db until a button is pressed, that unhide it. How to do that? Or if first idea is possible somehow it's even better.

Here's my game class:

```
public class Game extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

    Button b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9, b10;
    MediaPlayer buttonClicks;
    public boolean music;

    LinkedList<Long> mAnsweredQuestions = new LinkedList<Long>();

    private String generateWhereClause(){
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for (Long l : mAnsweredQuestions){
            result.append(" AND _ID <> " + l);
        }
        return result.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.game);

        addListenerOnButton();


        nextQuestion();
    }

    private void addListenerOnButton() {
        buttonClicks = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.button);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        b3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        b4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        b5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        b6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button6);
        b7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button7);
        b8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button8);
        b9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button9);

        b1.setOnClickListener(this);
        b2.setOnClickListener(this);
        b3.setOnClickListener(this);
        b4.setOnClickListener(this);
        b5.setOnClickListener(this);
        b6.setOnClickListener(this);
        b7.setOnClickListener(this);
        b8.setOnClickListener(this);
        b9.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    private void nextQuestion() {
        TestAdapter mDbHelper = new TestAdapter(this);
        mDbHelper.createDatabase();

        try{

            mDbHelper.open(); 

            Cursor c = mDbHelper.getTestData(generateWhereClause());

            mAnsweredQuestions.add(c.getLong(0));

            b1.setText(c.getString(2));
            b2.setText(c.getString(3));
            b3.setText(c.getString(4));
            b4.setText(c.getString(5));
            b5.setText(c.getString(6));
            b6.setText(c.getString(7));
            b7.setText(c.getString(8));
            b8.setText(c.getString(9));
            b9.setText(c.getString(10));
        }

            finally{
                mDbHelper.close();
            }

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.button1:
            if(music == true){
                buttonClicks.start();
                    }
            b1.setText(c.getString(2));// this is a good option, but can't use cursor
            b2.setEnabled(true);
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            if(music == true){
                buttonClicks.start();
                    }
            b3.setEnabled(true);
            break;
        case R.id.button3:
            if(music == true){
                buttonClicks.start();
                    }

            break;
        case R.id.button4:
            if(music == true){
                buttonClicks.start();
                    }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: "but my c cursor is not in activity scope" - why is that?

Comment: Well, you can see where it is in my class. Is there a way to place it somewhere else? I couldn't find where to place it without errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no builtin method to hide only the text on a button, but you could simply store the values from the database in a bunch of variables and not set those against the buttons until they're pressed.

That means you should change:

```
b1.setText(c.getString(2));
b2.setText(c.getString(3));
...
b9.setText(c.getString(10));
```

To something like:

```
String mButtonText1, mButtonText2, ... mButtonText9; // <-- class members

mButtonText1 = c.getString(2);
mButtonText2 = c.getString(3);
...
mButtonText9 = c.getString(10);
```

(alternatively, you could put these values in an array)

And then in `onClick()`:

```
b1.setText(mButtonText1);
```

To 'hide' the text on the button, simply call `setText()` with `""` or `null`.

You may be able to achieve the same effect by setting the button's text color to 'transparent', but I haven't tried that.

Comment: Thank you. This worked like a charm. I don't know how I didn't come to thid idea. :(

Answer (score 0):

How about passing the String-s to some intermediate storage in some variables and then, at appropriate time, setting the Buttons' texts from those strings?

Comment: I suppose that he want to have there the button label name, but he needs to hide it for while... so I think that setting font size to 0 is effective, even if it is not really nice, but when ever He's gonna need to show that label he has to just switch the font... I am not Java Expert I mostly code in C++ so there is maybe some method already implemented for this purpose...

Comment: Setting font size to 0 - I wouldn't bet on that because it might eat resources and might cause unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to find a solution for a symptom of a larger, underlying problem. If you're having difficulties sharing data between activities, you certainly shouldn't be heading in this direction.

That being said, to answer your specific question, you could set `textColor` to `android.R.color.transparent`.

Comment: I am likely doing something else wrong, but if I set the button text to transparent, it shows the color of the form behind the button, not the button backcolor. I opted to blank the text for this reason. But there are other reasons that I don't like to blank the text. I would also like some way of just making the text invisible without losing the content of the text. It seems this is unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is:

Setting text null or empty and in your java implementation, you set text.

Like this:

teste.xml:

```
<Button android:id="@+button/testebutton" android:text="" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Teste.java:

```
Button testeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.button.testebutton);
testeButton.setText("NEW TITLE");
```

Answer (score 0):

How about making the cursor an instance variable (of the class) instead of method-local variable? And maybe using http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_initialization ...

Comment: I will try also this solution. Thank you.

Comment: I get error again with your method.  I placed TestAdapter mDbHelper = new TestAdapter(this); and Cursor c = mDbHelper.getTestData(generateWhereClause()); in the scope of activity and upon starting the game I get error.

Comment: ,,Download not available.
Download permission denied by uploader. (0b67c2f5)''